# converting objective-c to swift : @() syntax

Tags: objective-c, swift

I was converting some objective-c to swift and came across this:

```
[_orderOfPlayers addObject:@{playerIdKey : [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID,
                                     randomNumberKey : @(_ourRandomNumber)}];
```

I don't know what this `@()` means, is it a literal?

How would I convert this into swift?

`_ourRandomNumber` is an `Int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a boxed expression (clang description [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-expressions)). In this case, all it does is to convert that int to a NSNumber.

So, if that argument has to be a NSNumber maybe you can use something like this in your Swift version:

```
NSNumber(integer: _ourRandomNumber)
```

Comment: what happens if `_ourRandomNumber` is a `UInt32`

Comment: @AbdulAhmad nice, yes, just chance the `integer` part accordingly :-) happy that it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a literal.

```
var myRandomNumberKey = NSNumber(integer:myInt)
```